# InDesign : Lock/unlock every layer of a document at once

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Is there a way to lock or unlock every layer not of page, but of the entire document?

CTRL + A and CTRL + L on every page is quite tedious.

With a script I guess?

Thanks,

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Layers panel**.

#### If all or some layers are locked and you want to unlock them all

- In the sandwich menu in the upper right corner, select *Unlock All Layers*.

#### If all layers are unlocked, and you want to lock them all

- Click the top layer, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the bottom layer to select all layers.
- In the sandwich menu in the upper right corner, select *Lock All Layers*.

#### If some layers are locked and you want to lock them all

- Unlock all layers as described above.
- Lock all layers as described above.

It's also pretty easy to just use the mouse to click and drag on the lock icons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly what I was looking for. The click and drag tip is also pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the CTRL+A (select all objects) and CTRL+L (lock objects) shortcuts, so my guess is, you're not actually talking about layers, but about locking/unlocking objects on pages.

In which case yes, the only way to automate that would be via scripting.

Comment: You're right. I confused the objets with the layers. In fact, for what I intend to dot, I want to lock either the layers or the objects,